# Running an SQL query in the loop of another SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

So I have the following query which fetches Active Competitions within an organisation and also tries to fetch the user who is leading the competition.

Currently the query correctly fetches the active competitions, and the totalPoints for each user. It now grabs all users, I only want it to grab the top user, so I am assuming the solution lies in the GROUP BY query, some sort of LIMIT?

In this image, you can see the results I am getting. As you can see, I am getting every user for each competition, where I only need the top user for each competition.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTxb3.png

Any idea on how I could solve this?

```
SELECT c.competitionId, c.name, c.start_date, c.end_date, a.userid, u.name, u.profilePic , 

SUM(activity_weight) AS totalPoints

FROM activity_entries a INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = a.userid INNER JOIN competitions c ON c.competitionId = a.competitionId

WHERE c.organisationId = 1 AND c.start_date < now() AND c.end_date > now() 
GROUP BY a.userid, c.competitionId ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Comment: Provide the table structure plz

Comment: select * from table inner join (select * from table2) as temp_table2 on temp_table2.id=table.id

Comment: As @Nadeem_MK suggests, if you want more detailed help, consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: I have nearly solved it now, just some small issue with the GROUP BY left. Thanks @Strawberry

Comment: Don't use images. Use sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way.  Just run one query with and join to the competitions table.  The second query you posted shows that you know how to join tables.

Comment: Correct, I know how to join the tables, but I am a bit confused whether it will loop correctly? I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: Also, how do I define the competitionId in the second query, if I get those from the first query? Hmm!

Comment: With a single query, there is no need to loop.  As for your second comment, competitionId is the field you use to join to the competitions table.  If you need it for anything else, include it in your select clause.